# Cosmosdb partial document update from an azure function

Tags: azure-functions, dependencies, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to do a partial update of a cosmosdb document from an Azure function and I am getting a run time exception with some conflicts with netty library dependencies and this is causing partial updates to fail.

I am using the following example but in an Azure function
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-java-sql-api-samples/blob/main/src/main/java/com/azure/cosmos/examples/patch/sync/SamplePatchQuickstart.java

Although the code complies and the azure function starts up, when I make a request I get the following exception

```
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.835Z] Executed 'Functions.ProductPartialUpdateFunction' (Failed, Id=218ce3d6-6bf3-4832-859e-8667ae22b6d1, Duration=783ms)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.835Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.ProductPartialUpdateFunction. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.835Z] Exception: ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.handler.logging.ByteBufFormat
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.835Z] Stack: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.835Z]      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.835Z]      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.835Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodInvokeInfo.invoke(JavaMethodInvokeInfo.java:22)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.835Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.EnhancedJavaMethodExecutorImpl.execute(EnhancedJavaMethodExecutorImpl.java:22)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.835Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.chain.FunctionExecutionMiddleware.invoke(FunctionExecutionMiddleware.java:19)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.835Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.chain.InvocationChain.doNext(InvocationChain.java:21)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.836Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaFunctionBroker.invokeMethod(JavaFunctionBroker.java:80)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.836Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:37)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.836Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:12)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.836Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.MessageHandler.handle(MessageHandler.java:44)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.836Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.JavaWorkerClient$StreamingMessagePeer.lambda$onNext$0(JavaWorkerClient.java:93)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.836Z]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:577)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.836Z]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.836Z]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.836Z]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.836Z]      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.836Z] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/handler/logging/ByteBufFormat
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.837Z]      at reactor.netty.transport.logging.ReactorNettyLoggingHandler.<init>(ReactorNettyLoggingHandler.java:65)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.837Z]      at reactor.netty.transport.logging.AdvancedByteBufFormat.toLoggingHandler(AdvancedByteBufFormat.java:109)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.837Z]      at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConfig.<clinit>(HttpClientConfig.java:711)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.837Z]      at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect.<init>(HttpClientConnect.java:84)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.837Z]      at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient.create(HttpClient.java:411)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.837Z]      at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.http.ReactorNettyClient.createWithConnectionProvider(ReactorNettyClient.java:94)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.837Z]      at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.http.HttpClient.createFixed(HttpClient.java:61)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.837Z]      at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl.httpClient(RxDocumentClientImpl.java:641)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.837Z]      at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl.<init>(RxDocumentClientImpl.java:434)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.837Z]      at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl.<init>(RxDocumentClientImpl.java:274)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.837Z]      at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl.<init>(RxDocumentClientImpl.java:240)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.837Z]      at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.AsyncDocumentClient$Builder.build(AsyncDocumentClient.java:252)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.837Z]      at com.azure.cosmos.CosmosAsyncClient.<init>(CosmosAsyncClient.java:171)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.837Z]      at com.azure.cosmos.CosmosClientBuilder.buildAsyncClient(CosmosClientBuilder.java:852)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.837Z]      at com.azure.cosmos.CosmosClient.<init>(CosmosClient.java:32)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.837Z]      at com.azure.cosmos.CosmosClientBuilder.buildClient(CosmosClientBuilder.java:868)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.837Z]      at com.viking.ProductPartialUpdateFunction.runMany(ProductPartialUpdateFunction.java:49)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.837Z]      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.837Z]      ... 15 more
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.837Z] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.handler.logging.ByteBufFormat
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.837Z]      at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.837Z]      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.837Z]      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.837Z]      ... 33 more
[2023-03-23T09:22:19.837Z] .
```

I understand that this error is happening due to conflict between the netty libraries being used by azure-cosmos and me including a explicit netty-all dependency in the pom.xml.

My pom.xml looks like below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.viking</groupId>
    <artifactId>VikingAzureFunctions</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Azure Java Functions</name>

    <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>confluent</id>
        <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-sdk-bom</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.10</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>1.22.0</azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>
        <azure.functions.java.library.version>2.2.0</azure.functions.java.library.version>
        <functionAppName>VikingAzureFunctions-1676901974803</functionAppName>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-cosmos -->



<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-cosmos -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-cosmos</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.43.Final</version>
</dependency>

        

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-handler -->

<!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.42.Final</version>
</dependency> -->

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>azure-cosmosdb</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.5</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
            <version>${azure.functions.java.library.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro-tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>



<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thoughtworks.xstream/xstream -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
    <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.20</version>
</dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.functions.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- function app name -->
                    <appName>${functionAppName}</appName>
                    <!-- function app resource group -->
                    <resourceGroup>java-functions-group</resourceGroup>
                    <!-- function app service plan name -->
                    <appServicePlanName>java-functions-app-service-plan</appServicePlanName>
                    <!-- function app region-->
                    <!-- refers https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/wiki/Azure-Functions:-Configuration-Details#supported-regions for all valid values -->
                    <region>westus</region>
                    <!-- function pricingTier, default to be consumption if not specified -->
                    <!-- refers https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/wiki/Azure-Functions:-Configuration-Details#supported-pricing-tiers for all valid values -->
                    <!-- <pricingTier></pricingTier> -->
                    <!-- Whether to disable application insights, default is false -->
                    <!-- refers https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/wiki/Azure-Functions:-Configuration-Details for all valid configurations for application insights-->
                    <!-- <disableAppInsights></disableAppInsights> -->
                    <runtime>
                        <!-- runtime os, could be windows, linux or docker-->
                        <os>windows</os>
                        <javaVersion>17</javaVersion>
                    </runtime>
                    <appSettings>
                        <property>
                            <name>FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION</name>
                            <value>~4</value>
                        </property>
                    </appSettings>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-functions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!--Remove obj folder generated by .NET SDK in maven clean-->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>obj</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>schema</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/</sourceDirectory>
              <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My azure function looks like below

```
package com.viking;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Optional;

import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpMethod;
import com.azure.cosmos.ConsistencyLevel;
import com.azure.cosmos.CosmosClient;
import com.azure.cosmos.CosmosClientBuilder;
import com.azure.cosmos.CosmosContainer;
import com.azure.cosmos.CosmosDatabase;
import com.azure.cosmos.models.CosmosContainerProperties;
import com.azure.cosmos.models.CosmosContainerResponse;
import com.azure.cosmos.models.CosmosDatabaseResponse;
import com.azure.cosmos.models.CosmosItemResponse;
import com.azure.cosmos.models.CosmosPatchItemRequestOptions;
import com.azure.cosmos.models.CosmosPatchOperations;
import com.azure.cosmos.models.PartitionKey;
import com.azure.cosmos.models.ThroughputProperties;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import com.microsoft.azure.functions.ExecutionContext;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpRequestMessage;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.AuthorizationLevel;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.BlobTrigger;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.FunctionName;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.HttpTrigger;
import com.viking.models.product.Product;

public class ProductPartialUpdateFunction {

    private CosmosClient client;

    private final String databaseName = "AzureSampleFamilyDB";
    private final String containerName = "FamilyContainer";

    private CosmosDatabase database;
    private CosmosContainer container;

    @FunctionName("ProductPartialUpdateFunction")
    public void runMany(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = { HttpMethod.GET,
                    HttpMethod.POST }, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            final ExecutionContext context) {

        client = new CosmosClientBuilder().endpoint("xxx")
                .key("xxx")
                // .preferredRegions(preferredRegions)
                .consistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.EVENTUAL).contentResponseOnWriteEnabled(true).buildClient();

        CosmosDatabaseResponse databaseResponse = client.createDatabaseIfNotExists(databaseName);
        database = client.getDatabase(databaseResponse.getProperties().getId());

        CosmosContainerProperties containerProperties = new CosmosContainerProperties(containerName, "/lastName");

        // Create container with 400 RU/s
        ThroughputProperties throughputProperties = ThroughputProperties.createManualThroughput(400);
        CosmosContainerResponse containerResponse = database.createContainerIfNotExists(containerProperties,
                throughputProperties);
        container = database.getContainer(containerResponse.getProperties().getId());

        CosmosPatchOperations cosmosPatchOperations = CosmosPatchOperations.create();
        cosmosPatchOperations.add("/testAttribute", false);
        CosmosPatchItemRequestOptions options = new CosmosPatchItemRequestOptions();
        try {
            CosmosItemResponse<Product> response = container.patchItem(request.getQueryParameters()
                    .get("id"),
                    new PartitionKey(request.getQueryParameters()
                            .get("country")),
                    cosmosPatchOperations, options, Product.class);
            context.getLogger().info("Item with ID {} has been patched " + response.getItem().getId());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried changing the netty version but everytime I change the version, i get some different error as azure-cosmos seems to have a dependency on 4.1.42.Final version.

I am also using the azure bom but still no difference.

Has any one successfully been able to do a partial update via an Azure function as I am unclear how to resolve this issue.

I also have a dependency on the following library but this doesnt seem to have any feature to do partial document updates. Is there any other way of performing partial document updates via azure functions as I have not been able to find any documentation around this.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-cosmosdb</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Some guidance or help will be really appreciated.

Based on Paizo's feedback, I have replaced the versioned netty dependency and added 'azure-core-http-netty' which is loading correctly from azure-bom but I am getting the following error now while connecting to the azure cosmosdb

```
^C^C[2023-03-23T09:52:04.992Z] Language Worker Process exited. Pid=6194.
[2023-03-23T09:52:04.992Z] /usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java exited with code 130 (0x82). java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class io.netty.channel.kqueue.AbstractKQueueChannel$AbstractKQueueUnsafe overrides final method io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.close(Lio/netty/channel/ChannelPromise;)V,23/03/23 09:50:37 ERROR scheduler.Schedulers: Scheduler worker in group main failed with an uncaught exception,java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class io.netty.channel.kqueue.AbstractKQueueChannel$AbstractKQueueUnsafe overrides final method io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.close(Lio/netty/channel/ChannelPromise;)V.
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Please edit your question to show your actual code (relevant code, doesn't need to be everything), sample input, expected vs actual behavior, etc. Nobody should need to click that link and visit that sample repo to understand what you're referring to.

Comment: Also, when editing, please re-post your error text as code, not as a giant quote - just post the error output with triple-backtick above and below.

Comment: you can solve the netty problem and other dependencies issues by using the azure bom, see https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/wiki/BOM-Guidelines

Comment: @DavidMakogon thank you for your feedback. I have updated my post based on your feedback now. Let me know if any further changes are needed.

Comment: @Paizo I am already using the azure bom but the netty dependency is not present in the bom. If I include the bom and remove the netty version, the pom.xml gives an error.

Comment: why are you then specifying the dependencies versions? The bom will pick the correct versions for you

Comment: @Paizo based on your comment, I have updated my pom with a new dependency from azure bom but getting a new java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError error which I have updated in my main post. Any clue what could be causing this?